# how to convert xml to html and send it to fax machine with images ? 

Tags: java, xml, image, xslt, fax

I have an XML file. I have to read the contents of this xml file and put it in html format and send it to fax with some images in java.

I cannot edit the xml file. not even to link it to the XSLT.

any ideas how i can achieve this ?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I tried converting the xml using xslt. but later I was informed that I cannot edit the xml. not even to link it to the XML.

Comment: There are different parser for XML, which one are you using? You should add code you have written already and describe there where you are stumbling.

Comment: actually it is a small xml file that I am dealing with. so I used xslt transformation to convert the xml to html. I linked the xslt to xml by editing the xml. now i am told i cannot edit xml, I couldn't find a way to link the xslt to the xml.

Comment: I did not write a parser. the objective is to read the contects from the xml file, put it in an html which has some images and send it to fax machine. I am not clear how I should approach this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Transformer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) to apply arbitrary XSLT to a document (XML or otherwise) using java.  Actual examples abound on this site and the rest of the internet.

As for the FAXing part, there are a lot of interesting hits on google for "java fax".